# char pointer in C not getting the good value

Tags: c, string, pointers, char

I want to create a function that takes a char or a string in C, so i the argument of the function is a char pointer.

```
int code(char* mot){
    char alphabet[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    if (strlen(mot) > 1){
        // If we give a word
        int longueur = strlen(mot);
        int resultat = 0;
        for (int i=1; i<longueur+1; i++){
            char l = mot[i-1];
            printf("%c\n", l);
            resultat += pow(26, (i-1))*code(&l);
        }
        return resultat;
    } else if (strlen(mot) == 1){
        // If we give a char
        char letter = *mot;
        char* pPosition = strchr(alphabet, letter);
        int index;
        if (pPosition != NULL){
            index = pPosition - alphabet + 1;         
        }
        return index;
    } else {
        printf("ERROR: length of word not valid");
        return -1;
    }
}
```

My function works if I replace `resultat += pow(26, (i-1))*code(&l);` with that `resultat += pow(26, (i-1))*code("a");`. I don't understand why when I use the pointer it don't take the char associated with the pointer. Altough, it displays me a segmentation fault error.

Comment: You can only use `strlen()` on a string, not a single `char`.

Comment: @Barmar Ohh, i didn't thought about that because it displays me 1 when i print strlen()

Comment: What is `l` in `code(&l)`?

Comment: That's just by accident. `strlen()` requires the argument to be a null-terminated string.

Comment: @Barmar any ideas of another function that works in my situation ? :)

Comment: Use different functions for strings and chars.

Comment: @001 I thought that create a medium variable will resolve my problem ...

Comment: If `l` is a single `char` (`char l;`) then `code(&l)` is only valid when `l` contains the null character value `'\0'` because `code` expects the parameter `mot` to point to a null-terminated string.

Comment: @001 `char l = mot[i-1];`

Comment: @001 the letter of the word entered as "mot"

Comment: Why do you start `i` from `1` and then subtract 1 wherever you use it? Loop from `0`.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks. Didn't see the recursive call.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you it's corrected. It didn't have any sense, altough I take the formula from an exercise  xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Barmar answered my question in comment.

it was the `strlen` function that cannot be used for `char` type.
I will create two different functions to resolve the problem.

Thank you @Barmar , @001 and @Ian Abott for your time.